# Angular UI-Router Template Provider (Access to Locals?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need access to resolves in my templateProvider. The documentation says this is possible does it doesn't look like it actually works. Does anyone know if I'm doing this wrong or if it simply doesn't work?

http://plnkr.co/edit/yitkre1ttB8TehbhClR2?p=preview

```
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('root', {
    url: '/root',
    resolve: {
      test: function() {
        return 'world';
      }
    },
    templateProvider: function(test) {
      return 'hello ' + test;
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('root');
});
```

Comment: it is version issue. "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js" add latest ui-router script will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this doesn't work. I found [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/330) trying to solve it myself too. :(

Comment: It has been fixed in version 0.2.15. The issue you've linked to has been resolved.